# Content Delivery Remote Server 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: content-delivery

Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful, and if I need to add more information please let me know.  Thank you.  Mike.

Using:
Tridion 2011.  .Net application
In IIS attempt to open site clicking on Browse.

Error Excerpt:
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Complete Error Log File contents:
mep.log
2015-04-07 14:32:09,759 [7] INFO  CustomTrace Module Begin Request: /
2015-04-07 14:32:09,790 [7] DEBUG VirtualPageModule Function app_BeginRequest start.
2015-04-07 14:32:09,806 [7] DEBUG LanguageManager Languages: en
2015-04-07 14:32:09,806 [7] DEBUG LanguageManager Split Languages Count: 1
2015-04-07 14:32:09,806 [7] DEBUG LanguageManager Language: en
2015-04-07 14:32:09,806 [7] DEBUG LanguageManager Language added: en
2015-04-07 14:32:09,853 [7] DEBUG VirtualAspxPage InitializeVirtualPage for url "http://167.236.210.139/";
2015-04-07 14:32:09,853 [7] DEBUG VirtualAspxPage Loading Page: E:\wwwroot\Published Content\MEP\en\default.aspx
2015-04-07 14:32:25,110 [7] FATAL VirtualPageModule Exception is occured, detailed info is: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Context Info ---- 
IsSimulated:
Virtual Page Path: E:\wwwroot\Published Content\MEP\en\default.aspx 
Raw Url: / 
Request Url: http://167.236.210.139/ 
Referrer Url:
Master Page:
Page Uri:
Page Parent ID:
Modified:
Language: en 
Show Breadcrumb:
Show Callus:
Show Emailus:
Show Print:
Show Share:
Brand Alt Name:
Site Edit Instruction: 
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, Uri baseUri, String entityName)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream inStream)
   at SPX.GDMP.Common.Extensions.LoadNoLock(XmlDocument document, String xmlFilePath) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Common\ExtensionMethods.cs:line 49
   at SPX.GDMP.Utility.SDLTridion.PresentationFramework.VirtualAspxPage..ctor() in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Utility\Presentation_Framework\SPXGDMPUtilityVirtualASPXPage.cs:line 110
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.InitVirtualPage() in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 136
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.DefaultRewriteHandler.Do(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\DefaultRewriteHandler.cs:line 51
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.DefaultRewriteHandler.Process(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\DefaultRewriteHandler.cs:line 253
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 31
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.UrlRewriteHandler.UrlRewriteHandler.ProcessRequest(VirtualPageStatus pageStatus, Boolean redirect) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\UrlRewriteHandler\UrlRewriteHandler.cs:line 45
   at SPX.GDMP.Web.HttpModule.VirtualPageModule.App_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\BuildAgentDirectory\4\WebTechnologies\Branch.Build.Website.All.All\src\WebApplication-branch\SPX.GDMP.Web\HttpModule\SPXGDMPUtilityHttpModule.cs:line 183
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-04-07 14:33:07,324 [5] INFO  CustomTrace Module Begin Request: /en/Error/
2015-04-07 14:33:07,324 [5] DEBUG VirtualPageModule Function app_BeginRequest start.
2015-04-07 14:33:07,339 [5] DEBUG VirtualAspxPage InitializeVirtualPage for url "http://167.236.210.139/en/Error/";
2015-04-07 14:33:07,339 [5] DEBUG VirtualAspxPage Function PopulatePageObject start.
2015-04-07 14:33:07,339 [5] DEBUG VirtualAspxPage Function PopulatePageObject end.
2015-04-07 14:33:07,339 [5] DEBUG VirtualPageModule Function app_BeginRequest end.

Answer (score 4):

Why did you tag this question with content-manager and broker? Looking at the stack trace, it seems that neither is involved in the problem.
That is: the stack trace is full of custom code (from SPX.GDMP.* namespaces) and then transitions to System.Xml namespace in which the exception occurs; seems to me you will just have to debug this custom code.

Just looking at the stack trace, I can do an educated guess: it seems the custom code (in particular: the SPX.GDMP.Utility.PresentationFramework.VirtualAspxPage constructor) is trying to load an XML file which has a DOCTYPE statement containing external entity definitions. When the XML parser is trying to access these external entity definitions (by URL), the remote web server where the URL refers to returns an HTTP 500 (internal server error) response.